# Flask unit-test: Unable to mock a function in a post request

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking

I have the following flask app.

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask, request
from predict import query_sku

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    content = request.json
    max_results = content["resultSize"]
    input_sku_list = content["sku"]

    skus = query_sku(input_sku_list, max_results)
    return {"sku": skus}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I wrote a unit-test for it using `pytest` and tried to mock the `query_sku` function using `unittest.mock`.

```
import sys
from unittest.mock import Mock

import pytest

import app

def test_api_mocked_model():
    sys.modules["predict"] = Mock()
    from predict import query_sku
    query_sku.return_value = "dummy"

    with app.app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.post('/predict', json={"resultSize":10,"sku": "x"}).json

    assert response == {"sku": "dummy"}
    del sys.modules['predict']
```

But I was unable to mock that function within the request. It just gave the following assertion error.

```
>       assert response == {"sku": "dummy"}
E       AssertionError: assert None == {'sku': 'dummy'}
E         +None
E         -{'sku': 'dummy'}

tests/unit_tests/test_api.py:34: AssertionError
```

How can I get it to work?

**[EDIT]**

I added in the `query_sku` function below. Intentionally return a value that is different from the Mock function return_value.

```
# predict.py
def query_sku(input_sku_list, topn):
    return "actual function"
```

But the unit-test is still querying from the actual function, as shown below.

```
assert response == {"sku": "dummy"}
E       AssertionError: assert {'sku': 'actual function'} == {'sku': 'dummy'}
E         Differing items:
E         {'sku': 'actual function'} != {'sku': 'dummy'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_api_mocked_model():
     ## sys.modules["predict"] = Mock() ## why sys module ?
    from predict import query_sku
    query_sku = MagicMock(return_value="dummy") # mock directly 
  


    with app.app.test_client() as client:
        response = client.post('/predict', json={"resultSize":10,"sku": "x"}).json

    assert response == {"sku": "dummy"}
    del sys.modules['predict']
```

Could you try this code ?

Comment: Hi, it gave `TypeError: query_sku() missing 1 required positional argument: 'topn'`  for the line `query_sku(mock, "dummy")` becos the function is the actual one and it expects more args. I change the lines to `query_sku = Mock(); query_sku.return_value = "dummy"` which mock the function and the return value, but it is still not mocked to the func in the flask request

Comment: U wrote to `import MagicMock` but it was not used in the test func, would that make a difference?

Comment: Could you try again with `MagicMock` ? I have updated the answer

Comment: hmm, it gave the same error `TypeError: query_sku() missing 1 required positional argument: 'topn'` :(

Comment: Could you provide the definition for. function `query_sku` , the reason for the error is in your `app.py`,  not the test file

Comment: I have added the function for `query_sku in my post, u can see the pytest still takes the original, not mocked `query_sku` defined in the unit-test

Comment: The reason is that your code is failed in `app.y` (unittest ran correctly) . Why ? because your function requires 3 parameters `def query_sku(model, input_sku_list, topn)`, but  in `app.py` , you call the function with only 2 input `skus = query_sku(input_sku_list, max_results)` => To overcome this, please call `query_sku` with 3 parameters OR set default value for topn (eg: `def query_sku(model, input_sku_list, topn=False)`

Comment: thanks for being patient with my queries~ That was actually an error on my part, the actual function was abit complex, so I reduced the unnecessary portions for clarity, the `model` variable was not required~ and I have edited in my question. To surmise, I believe it is still unable to do the mocking.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer above did not work for me. Rather than using MagicMock, I  used @mock.patch and that worked. And it is less complicated too. For example, in your app.py, you can have an API endpoint that you want to stub out with a mock:

##### app.py

```
def fetch_nodes(usr, passwd, hostname, node_name):
  sftp_connection = get_sftp_connection(usr, passwd, hostname)
  nodes = sftp_connection.listdir_attr(node_name)
  return nodes
```

Now in test_app.py, you can stub it out like this:

##### test_app.py

```
from app import app
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class FlaskTest(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch('app.fetch_nodes')
  def test_list_child_nodes(self, mocked):
    tester = app.test_client(self)

    mocked.return_value = []

    response = tester.post("/api/listchildnodes", json={
      'usr': 'test',
      'jwt': 'test',
      'node_name': 'test',
    })

    statuscode = response.status_code
    self.assertEqual(statuscode, 200)
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

The important thing is the definition of mock.patch('app.fetch_nodes') which references the fetch_nodes function in app.py and secondly it is passed to the test function as "mocked". Then we set the return value of "mocked". And finally call the flask endpoint. Now the flask endpoint will use the mock instead of actually hitting an sftp server.